# SlidingTabLayout backgroundcolor

Tags: android, tabs, android-resources

I am trying to change the tab background color of the SlidingTabLayout described in (https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html).

I managed to get the entire thing working. But when I change the tabresource color on line 183 for example:

```
 textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
```

The background of the tab becomes white, but the indicator does not appear at all.

Can someone please advise on how to just change the background color but have the indicator work as usual?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't believe I missed this.

Put this in the constructor:

```
this.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tabBgColor));
```

Comment: Hi!!!, you are the life saver, thank you very much, +1 for answer & +1 for question tooo... if you know, can you tell me how to put gradient shadow background?. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could also set the background in the layout XML:

```
<SlidingTabLayout
    ...
    android:background="@color/tabBgColor"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is changing tab background color via SlidingTabStrip.

You need to add just 3 lines of code to **SlidingTabLayout.java**

```
public void setTabsBackgroundColor(int color) {
    mTabStrip.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Usage:

```
slidingTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
slidingTabs.setTabsBackgroundColor(YOUR_COLOR_GOES_HERE));
```

I hope that will also work for you.